# R scatterplot y-axis grouped

Tags: r, scatter-plot

My df is a database of individuals (rows) and amount they spent (column) in one activity. I want to draw a scatterplot in R that has the following characteristics:

x-axis: log(amount spent)
y-axis: log(number of people that spent this amount)

This is how far I got:

```
plot(log(df$Amount), log(df$???))
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

My df looks something like this:

```
  df   
  Name    Surname   Amount
  John     Smith     223
  Mary    Osborne    127
  Mark     Bloke      45
```

This is what I have in mind (taken from a paper by Chen (2012))

[image]

Comment: It might be useful to provide a reproducible example of your code. So how dies the `df` look like.

Comment: hm, so you expect to have more then one person spending exactly the same amount as 223? In this case `table(df$Amount)` would return the numbers.

Comment: Thanks @drmariod - I know from sumstats that the amount spent by individuals in my dataset goes from $1 (min) to $200 (max). I would like to see on the y-axis the frequency of individuals that spent a certain amount, broken down by $5 units. That is: my y-axis will go from 1 to 200 by units of 5 and it will represent the log of the number of individuals that spent an amount that is within those parameters. Example, if 400 individuals spent an amount between $ and $5 I would like to see log(400) on the plot. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: It sounds like you want to pre-process the data first, grouping the data by `Amount` in to bins (maybe some combination of dividing and `floor`ing the `Amount`, or simply `cut`), grouping by the bin, then plotting this new `data-frame` of bin (with appropriate bin names representing the `Amount`) against the bin frequencies on a `log` scale, similarly to what you've tried.

Comment: @AkhilNair would I overkill it a bit if I created a new column that assigns value of 1, 2, 3, etc. based on amount spent, say '1 == $1-5', '2==$6-10', etc.?

Comment: Sounds fine to me, `cut(x, breaks = seq(0, 200, by = 5))` will do the trick, where `x` is the `Amount`. If you then go for `as.numeric` and multiply by `5`, the assigned new column will be the ceiling of the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales) # To let you make plotted points transparent
# Make some toy data that matches your df's structure
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Name = rep(letters, 4), Surname = rep(LETTERS, 4), Amount = rnorm(4 * length(LETTERS), 200, 50))
# Use dplyr to get counts of loans in each 5-dollar bin, then merge those counts back
# into the original data frame to use as y values in plot to come.
dfsum <- df %>%
    mutate(Bins=cut(Amount, breaks=seq(round(min(Amount), -1) - 5, round(max(Amount) + 5, -1), by=5))) # Per AkhilNair's comment
    group_by(Bins) %>%
    tally() %>%
    merge(df, ., all=TRUE)
# Make the plot with the new df with the x-axis on a log scale
with(dfsum, plot(x = log(Amount), y = n, ylab="Number around this amount", pch=20, col = alpha("black", 0.5)))
```

Here's what that produced:
[image]